# Apache Poi Problems setting up in command line

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to make use of Apache-Poi for a program I am working on, but I recently ran into problems trying to actually implement it. I downloaded the files, and unzipped them, but my program won't recognize it. I have:

- tried adding the .jar files to the classpath
- tried adding the folder with Apache Poi to the classpath
- tried putting the Poi files in with my class files (bad idea, but had to try)

To describe my dependencies:[image]:

I am not sure how to add the apache poi library to my program. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify your `apache-poi` jar as follow.

```
C:/demo/myprogram>javac -cp C:/project/jars/apache-poi.jar Main.java
C:/demo/myprogram>java -cp C:/project/jars/apache-poi.jar. Main
```

Here we specify the jar to classpath during the compilation and execution,in this way you will be able to access the `apache-poi` classes.

If you want to add multiple jars you can use `*` for that,

```
java -cp C:/project/jars/*. Main
```

Comment: Will this add the apache Poi to the classpath or switch to it?

Comment: It will add it to the class path.